# iOS Push services work for development but not distribution

Tags: ios, push-notification, push

Using my development certificate, I am able to successfully receive pushes. However, even though my certificate says that push is active for the distribution, every time I submit or test the distribution one (under the debug), push appears inactive. For instance, when I submit, I get an email from itunesconnect stating that push notification apis were detected but there was not a proper aps-environment. From debugging, I get no dialogue whatsoever asking to accept push notifications...what could possibly be going on if the provisioning profile says it is active?

Comment: Maybe you are sending some push notifications to development tokens which causes Apple's server to disconnect your server.

Comment: I'm just looking for the "accept notifications" popup really. It pops up for dev, but not production.

Comment: Try follow this guide for the right way of exporting your certificate: https://wiki.pushapps.mobi/display/PUSHAPPS/iOS+Getting+Started